# Properties of the Theta function

Tags: continuity, fourier-analysis, theta-functions

Define the $\vartheta :\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$\vartheta (s) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi m^2s}$$

Is this a smooth ($C^{\infty}$) function? I would like to think so, but I'm not sure due to the sum from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

On top of this, I was told that I should try to show

$$s^{-1/2}\vartheta(1/s) = \vartheta(s), \quad s > 0$$

To me this smells like I should use Fourier series, but I'm not sure how to use Fourier series on a function with an infinite series.

Could anyone possibly help me show these two facts?

Comment: Yes, the series converges uniformly on compact subsets of the right half-plane, so is holomorphic there.

Comment: See [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula).

Comment: Holomorphic is for $s \in \Bbb{C}, \Re(s) > 0$. For $s=x > 0$ that it is smooth is obvious by absolute convergence of all the series of derivatives. Let $h_x(t) = e^{-\pi x t^2}$ its Fourier transform is $x^{-1/2} h_{1/x}(\xi)$. Let $f_x(t) = \sum_n h_x(t+n)$ its Fourier series is $\sum_k \hat{f_x}(k)e^{2i \pi k t}=\sum_k x^{-1/2} h_{1/x}(k) e^{2i \pi k t}$. Letting $t=0$ you have your result.

Comment: Thanks folks. If any of you want to write out an answer I'd be happy to accept it. Just a small question, @reuns. You say "letting $t=0$ gives the result", but you have to use that together with the Poisson summation formula, yes?